# Progress bar is not visible before the video plays

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-videoview

My video plays in a dailog box on button click. There is a progress bar that should be visible before the video starts playing. But when the app runs there is no progress bar visible before the video plays. Don't know what the problem is?
My code

**mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
VideoView videoview;
ProgressBar progressBar;
Context context;
String VideoURL = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            plyvido();

        }
    });

}
//@Override
public void plyvido(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.videodialog);
    dialog.show();
    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
        MainActivity.this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());

    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    videoview = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videodialogVideoView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
    videoview.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
    videoview.start();



    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1,
                                                       int arg2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });

            }
        });


}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

move progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); before   videoview = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videodialogVideoView);

Comment: Tried as you said. The app crashes. Getting nullpointerexception in loggcat

Answer (score 0):

This one is for progress dialog spin style:
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); 
    dialog.show();

Comment: Thanks for telling me about spinstyle. Appreciate it very much. But my problem is unsolved